# Calling a 3D meshgrid into Simscape

Tags: matlab, 3d, modeling, heat, simscape

I have produced a TPMS 3D surface mesh in MATLAB. Is there a way I can call it by code into Simscape? I want to do some flow and HX modeling.

I tried to save it as .stl but seems like my MATLAB can't write or read .stl. Is there a way I can go around stl? I produced the 3D in MATLAB, why shouldn't SIMCAPE be able to call/import it?